# Background Image not set to full height

Tags: html, css

I have a `background-image` which should take the full height of my browser, also of mobile devices. But the image not take the full height of any browser or device. The rest of from the end of the image to the end of the window, has the background-color white :

[image]

And here is my css:

```
.full-tab-container {
 padding: 0px;   
 background-image: url(../img/Picture1.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: top;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: Create [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - without it we can only guess. My guess is that everything works just fine, only some floated content inside `.full-tab-container` is overflowing it.

Answer (score 0):

The element with the class full-tab-container should be at height: 100%, and so should all parents.
Also, would it make sense to set the background for the body instead?